# How to implement 2 identical branches of layers sharing the same weights in Keras with Theano

Tags: python, model, architecture, keras, theano

I am trying to implement 2 identical branches sharing the same weights to a certain extent. The graphic you see here [image] is a simplified model of what I have. So I have an input : a negative and a positive one, all the layers from conv1_1_x untill Rpn, should have the same weights. What I have tried to implement so far is:

```
    def create_base_network(input_shape, branch, input_im, img_input, roi_input):
            def creat_conv_model(input_shape):
                branch = Sequential()
                branch.add(Conv2D(64,filter_size,subsample = strides, input_shape=input_shape  ,  activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform' ,name='conv1_1_'+str(branch)))
                branch.add(Conv2D(64,filter_size, subsample = strides,  activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',name='conv1_2_1'+str(branch)))
                branch.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=pool_stride, name='pool1_'+str(branch)))
                branch.add(Conv2D(128,filter_size,subsample = strides, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',name='conv2_1_'+str(branch)))

                return branch
            shared_layers =  creat_conv_model(input_shape)
            rpn_output = rpn(shared_layers(input_im),9,branch)   
            model = Model([img_input, roi_input], rpn_output[:2])

            return model


Branch_left = create_base_network((64, 64, 3), 1, img_input_left, img_input, roi_input)
Branch_right = create_base_network((64, 64, 3), 2, img_input_right, img_input, roi_input)
```

When I run this, I get the following error :

```
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor /input_2 at layer "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why two if they're identical and use the same input?

Comment: The input would be 2 different images. One negative input and one positive input.  I edited my question with a new implementation. Could you please confirm, if the weights are indeed shared in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the model to share weights, you must create it only once. You cannot create two models.

```
shared_model = creat_conv_model((64, 64, 3), left)
```

If `rpn` is also a model to be shared, you must create it one time only:

```
rpn_model = create_rpn(...)
```

Then you pass the inputs:

```
img_neg_out = shared_model(img_input_left)
img_neg_out = rpn_model(img_neg_out)

img_pos_out = shared_model(img_input_right)
img_pos_out = rpn_model(img_pos_out)
```

About creating the models `branch_left` and `branch_right`, that depends on what you want to do and how you want to train.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your contribution. Did you see my edit? Isn't this what I am also doing ? Or is the fact that I am changing the name of the layers according  name='conv1_2_1'+str(brh) with brh = 1 for lleft and 2 for right breaks the logic?

Comment: No, you're creating two models. They will not share weights.

Comment: Is there actually a way to do this with a functional API model since it takes the input from the beginning ?

Comment: You're already doing it with a functional API model. Having a sequential segment in the middle doesn't make it different. :) --- If you want, I can create the model from your picture entirely in the answer. (But I'll consider that you have two data boxes)

Comment: I have it. Thank you Daniel!